# What is the corrrect way to install remote Helm applications via Argo CD?

Tags: helm, argocd

I need to install loki-stack to my k8s cluster, previously I need to change `retention_deletes_enabled` and `retention_period` in `charts/loki/values.yaml`.

What should I do to achieve this?

The problem is that there are several `values.yaml` files and I can't change loki values (`charts/loki/values.yaml`), I only can change the main `loki-stack/values.yaml` of this app when I create new application in Argo CD.

In general is it the correct way to clone the repo or doing `helm pull` then add this code to local git repository and create app from it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to configure the "Loki" Helm chart when installing the "Loki-Stack" Helm chart.

The Loki-Stack Helm chart has several sub-charts (dependencies), each of which is available with its own name through the `values.yaml`: https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/loki-stack/values.yaml

So for example if you want to configure where Loki stores the logs, you would do that as follows **in the loki-stack Helm Helm chart**:

```yaml
loki: # <-- extra nesting required to access values of sub-chart
  loki: 
    storage:
      type: 'filesystem'
```

Note that you need the extra "loki" entry to correctly pass the values to the sub-chart. Read me more here: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/